# Excel Conditional Formatting vs. a Reference Table

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I'm trying to determine how to format a column of values against a reference table.  If this is possible, I feel like it would require use of the "forumula" conditional formatting style; however, I haven't had much experience with that, and I haven't been able to find exactly what I'm looking for--not sure I'm correctly stating my problem.

[image: Example - Data and Reference Table]

The intent is to be able to "Red/Green" the cells in the Column B depending on which "Level" is indicated in Cell B1: if the value in column B is greater than or equal to the value in the reference chart for that Level, the value in column B should turn green, otherwise it should turn red.

I have hundreds of columns of information like this, all of which needs to be formatted in the same manner.  This information will also be regularly updated ("Level" value in B1, "1/2/3" values in column B).

I'm using Excel 2016, if that is relevant information.

Any help would be greatly appreciated--I can provide additional information if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

made a really basic VBA script for this if you just want to use that. code is below.

```
Public Sub UpdateTheLevel()
Dim Currentlevel, templevel As String
Dim i, j, MaxLevel, column, MaxSkill, currlevel, wantedlevel As Integer
column = 0
''Need to set MaxLevel, MaxSkill
Currentlevel = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 1).Value
For i = 4 To MaxLevel
    templevel = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, i).Value
    If templevel = Currentlevel Then
        column = i
        Exit For
    Else
        Next i
If column = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Level Not Found."
Else
    For j = 3 To MaxSkill
        currlevel = Cells(j, 2).Value
        wantedlevel = Cells(j, column).Value
        If currlevel < wantedlevel Then
            Range (Cells(j, 2)), Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        Else
            Range (Cells(j, 2)), Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        Next j
End Sub
```

You could tie this into a form to run from a button press or whenever the file is opened.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without VBA, using two conditional formatting rules that use formulas to determine the format.

Select B3 to B17, taking great care that B3 is the active cell. Then create two rules.

Formula for red:

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(B3),B3<INDEX($D$3:$H$17,ROW(B3)-2,MATCH($B$1,$D$2:$H$2,0)))
```

Formula for green:

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(B3),B3>=INDEX($D$3:$H$17,ROW(B3)-2,MATCH($B$1,$D$2:$H$2,0)))
```

[image]